# Different packageNameSuffix with custom view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-view

I was wondering how to correctly include a custom View when using different packageNameSuffix values.

build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        packageNameSuffix ".release"
    }

    debug {
        packageNameSuffix ".debug"
    }
}
```

view.xml

```
<com.example.app.widget.View
    xmlns:ex="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.app"
    android:id="@+id/id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ex:param1="100"
    ex:param2="200"
/>
```

Gradle build errors after adding custom suffixes

```
Error:(114) No resource identifier found for attribute 'param1' in package 'com.example.app'
Error:(114) No resource identifier found for attribute 'param2' in package 'com.example.app'
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you can fix this if you want to use your packagename in it, but if you replace the namespace with "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" it should work fine

Comment: Far from ideal but should work - for now. No other solutions? :)